# Displaying named outlet routes as array

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to navigate from one page to another in a named outlet and pass queryparam-data.

So far I have this:

```
this.navCtrl.navigateForward('tabs/(more:tab/detail)', true, {
      queryParams: {
        id: '123'
      }
    });
```

My problem now is that due to a bug in Angular, the query params only get passed when the url is put into the function as an array. (The function declaration though wrongly suggests otherwise.)

My problem is that I want to rewrite the url into an array that I can pass but I do not know how to go about the named outlet. This syntax is new to me.

The url works fine as a string. How do I split up the fragments into an array and keep the outlet information?